# Nginx Web Server Error - upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a nginx web server set up running two sites i am developing, they are basically the same site with the same config, built on Laravel framework. Both have a login setup but one is giving me a 502 error anytime i attempt to login. Anytime i attempt to login i get a 502 error and if i check the nginx error log i see the following:

> 2020/10/21 22:26:59 [error] 10400#10400: *12 upstream sent too big
> header while reading response header from upstream, client:
> 162.158.179.216, server: vms2.medlab.co, request: "POST /login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host:
> "vms2.medlab.co", referrer: "https://vms2.medlab.co/"

My conf file for the site is as follows, which is excactly the same as my other site which runs perfectly fine:

```
#http
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    vms2.medlab.co;
    root           /var/www/vms.medlab.co/current/public;
    index          index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
      include         fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

# HTTPS
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name vms2.medlab.co;
  root        /var/www/vms.medlab.co/current/public;
  index       index.php index.html index.htm;


  #ssl on;
  ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/cloudflare-medlab.co.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/cloudflare-medlab.co.key;

  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }


  location / {
    access_log /var/www/vms.medlab.co/logs/access.log combined;
    error_log /var/www/vms.medlab.co/logs/error.log;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I have found a bunch of issues people have had in regards to the fast cgi and have tried a few quick fixes but have had no luck so far. Has nayone run into anything similar and have anything else i should try?

Thanks in advance

[image: 502 Error in chrome]

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue!

Had to add the following the nginx.conf file

```
    http { 
...
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 90;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 90;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 90;
}
```